# Resample a dataframe with n day window

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I know I can resample daily data, by month, like this:

```
df = data.resample('M')
```

But how do I resample by an arbitrary length, say 180?

```
df = data.resample('Days', 180) # six months # I am just guessing here
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the rule directly

```
df = data.resample('180D')
```

For a list of possibilities on rules, please [refer to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects). There's a nice summary table in this link.

Comment: Thanks. But the return is not a dataframe anymore?

Comment: I might not have asked the right question. I just want the entries of the dataframe that are n days apart and throw out all the rows in between of the dataframe

Comment: @Ivan please provide a [mcve]